# using mixitup plugin with a large number of items. how can i reduce filtering time?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm using the mixitup plugin to sort a large list.
Eventually there will be about ~740 entries in the list and I've got about 250 entries in there so far.
Sorting with the full list is very slow and I can only imagine it will get worse once all the entries are in.

Each entry follows this format:

```
<li class="mix grass def kalos" data-no="650" data-name="Chespin" data-hp="56" data-att="61" data-def="65" data-spa="48" data-spd="45" data-spe="38">
    <div class="meta no">650</div>
    <div class="meta name">
        <div class="img_wrapper">
            <img src="images/pokemon/650-chespin.png" onload="imgLoaded(this)"/>
        </div>
        <div class="titles">
            <h2>Chespin</h2>
            <p><img src="images/type/grass.png"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meta ability"><ul><li><div title="#overgrow">Overgrow</div></li><li><div title="#bulletproof"><i>Bulletproof</i></div></li></ul></div>
    <div class="meta ev"><ul><li>1 Defense</li></ul></div>
    <div class="meta hp">56</div>
    <div class="meta att">61</div>
    <div class="meta def">65</div>
    <div class="meta spa">48</div>
    <div class="meta spd">45</div>
    <div class="meta spe">38</div>
</li>
```

As you can see there is some repetitive data in that the first li class and data tags that correspond to data in the other divs. The items in the li class are used by the plugin to sort and filter while the content in the divs are what we see.

I'm thinking there's a javascript that can pull the numbers/data from within the li tag and automatically drop them into the respective divs but this would have to he done for each li item. Would this work in helping reduce the filtering time on the live site or just build time since I have to plug all these values in manually?

Plugin site: http://www.mixitup.io
Working site: http://www.color-mode.net/xy/pokedex.php